# How to Resolve Custom Place Holders in Email Template

Tags: c#

I have to send mail while certain action takes place in application.
While sending mail i have to fetch email template, email templates contains placeholders like {CustomerName} {CustomerAddress}. 
I am not able to determine what is the best practice to resolve placeholder, i googled it but no useful results.
Below is the solution i have arrived at, if any other best practices available suggest .

```
public class EmailTemplateResolver<T> where T : class
{
    public string resolveTemplate(T dataContainer, string Template)
    {
        string pattern = @"pattern";
        MatchCollection placeHolders = Regex.Matches(Template, pattern);
        foreach (var item in placeHolders)
        {
            //Find data will provide original data from dataContainer and place holder text will be removed from template
            Template = Template.Replace(item.ToString(), FindData(dataContainer, item.ToString())); 
        }

        return Template;
    }

    //every values in placeholder will be property of dataContainer object
    public string FindData(T dataContainer, string Property) 
    {
        string data=string.Empty;

        //use reflection to find the property value, use recursion to find the original value in nested object

        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve your email template (or any templates) I advise you these methods :

- 1' - Method : Use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method and change your placeholders to : {0}, {1}, etc.
- 2' - Method : Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for replacing each placeholders with the correct value.
- 3' - Method Use [RazorEngine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/). It's the Razor template engine usable out from ASP.

For me, the best way is to use a solid existing template engine like RazorEngine or [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) for example.

There are a lot of other ways. Hope this help you and be indulgent with my English.

Comment: I haven't thought about using Razor Engine, thanks for your suggestion. Now i am trying 3rd Method.